# Using jq to fetch and show key value with quotes

Tags: json, jq

I have a file that looks as below:

```
{
    "Job": {
        "Name": "sample_job",
        "Description": "",
        "Role": "arn:aws:iam::00000000000:role/sample_role",
        "CreatedOn": "2021-10-21T23:35:23.660000-03:00",
        "LastModifiedOn": "2021-10-21T23:45:41.771000-03:00",
        "ExecutionProperty": {
            "MaxConcurrentRuns": 1
        },
        "Command": {
            "Name": "glueetl",
            "ScriptLocation": "s3://aws-sample-s3/scripts/sample.py",
            "PythonVersion": "3"
        },
        "DefaultArguments": {
            "--TempDir": "s3://aws-sample-s3/temporary/",
            "--class": "GlueApp",
            "--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log": "true",
            "--enable-glue-datacatalog": "true",
            "--enable-metrics": "true",
            "--enable-spark-ui": "true",
            "--job-bookmark-option": "job-bookmark-enable",
            "--job-insights-byo-rules": "",
            "--job-language": "python",
            "--spark-event-logs-path": "s3://aws-sample-s3/logs"
        },
        "MaxRetries": 0,
        "AllocatedCapacity": 100,
        "Timeout": 2880,
        "MaxCapacity": 100.0,
        "WorkerType": "G.1X",
        "NumberOfWorkers": 100,
        "GlueVersion": "2.0"
    }
}
```

I want to get key/value from `"Name"`, `"--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log": ""` and `"--enable-metrics": ""`. So, I need to show the info like this:

```
"Name" "sample_job"
"--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log" ""
"--enable-metrics" ""
```

`UPDATE`

Follow the tips from @Inian and @0stone0 I came close to it:

`jq -r '(.Job ) + (.Job.DefaultArguments | { "--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log", "--enable-metrics"}) | to_entries[] | "\"\(.key)\" \"\(.value)\""'`

This extract the values I need but show all another key/values.

Comment: Your JSOn isn;t valid. Please fix it

Comment: it's a JSON that came from AWS, I just cut a few lines

Comment: There is one closing bracket missing, please show the correct data order. Is the `DefaultArguments` part of `Job` ? PLease make sure linters understand your json

Comment: This is a snippet from an AWS Glue Jobs and I get the JSON with `aws glue get-job --job-name sample_job`. And, yes `DefaultArguments`is part of `Job`.

Comment: Not sure what your comments on my now deleted answer mean. I posted an answer based on your input provided. If your are testing this on a different JSON, it can't work

Comment: Inian, you are completely right, and my apologies. I was think that snippet are sufficiently, but the original JSON has another brace that give error

Answer (score 0):

Since you're JSON isn't valid, I've converted it into:

```json
{
    "Job": {
        "Name": "sample_job",
        "Role": "sample_role_job"
    },
    "DefaultArguments": {
        "--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log": "test_1",
        "--enable-metrics": ""
    },
    "Timeout": 2880,
    "NumberOfWorkers": 10
}
```

Using the following filter:

```
"Name \(.Job.Name)\n--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log \(.DefaultArguments."--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log")\n--enable-metrics \(.DefaultArguments."--enable-metrics")"
```

We use string interpolation to show the desired output:

```
Name sample_job
--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log test_1
--enable-metrics
```

```
jq --raw-output '"Name \(.Job.Name)\n--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log \(.DefaultArguments."--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log")\n--enable-metrics \(.DefaultArguments."--enable-metrics")"'
```

##### [Online Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/VuhGbtLK30)

Comment: OP wants to quote both key and value

Comment: Hi Ostone0, thank you.

No problems with quotes, but no works:

`cat file.json | jq -r '"Name \(.Job.Name)\n--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log \(.DefaultArguments."--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log")\n--enable-metrics \(.DefaultArguments."--enable-metrics")"'` >>> All jobs with value like `"--enable-metrics" "true"` output with null